# Google YouTube API -- 401 on a delete request

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to delete videos via the YouTube API and getting a 401 status code telling me that login is required:

```
YouTube delete exception: Client error: `DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=qHwE11JqiW8&onBehalfOfContentOwner=SNIP&prettyPrint=1` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "message": "Login Required", (truncated...)
```

Here's the code creating my Google client object:

```
    $google_client = new Google_Client();
    $google_client->setHttpClient($this->httpClient);
    $google_client->addScope([\Google_Service_YouTube::YOUTUBE, \Google_Service_YouTubePartner::YOUTUBEPARTNER]);
    // This ensures the token is refreshed automatically for the life of the
    // client.
    $google_client->setAccessType('offline');
    if (!empty($google_auth_config['client_id_json'])) {
      $decoder = new JsonDecode(TRUE);
      $google_client->setAuthConfig($decoder->decode($google_auth_config['client_id_json'], 'json'));
    }
    if (!empty($google_auth_config['refresh_token'])) {
      $google_client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($google_auth_config['refresh_token']);

    }
    if (!empty($google_auth_config['redirect_uri'])) {
      $google_client->setRedirectUri($google_auth_config['redirect_uri']);
    }

    return $google_client;
```

var_dump($google_client) has this, which sure looks like it's got the auth pieces it needs (access_token and refresh_token).
`["token":"Google_Client":private]=> array(6) { ["access_token"]=> string(131) "a big long hash looking thing generated by Google Client fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken()" ["expires_in"]=> int(3600) ["scope"]=> string(86) "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube" ["token_type"]=> string(6) "Bearer" ["created"]=> int(1566992903) ["refresh_token"]=> string(45) "token generated by Google Oauth2" }`

Comment: PS -- $queryParams does include the correct `onBehalfOfContentOwner` value.

Comment: You should read the full response not just the status code it will give you an idea of whats going on.

Comment: I added another statement to print out the message body.  There isn't one, so no help there, either.

Comment: id10t error here.  All that code is doing for response is creating a new one, it's not getting the result of the service call.

Answer (score -1):

If you check the documentation for that method it tells you what the response means

[video.delete](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/delete)

[image]

Comment: Right, if successful, I should get a 204.  I'm getting a 200 and would like to know why.  The docs have all kinds of help on 4xx, but nothing on 2xx.

Comment: TBH in my exprece 200 and 204 are the same thing in google apis it could just be a missing documentation notice.   what is the full response do a dump on $response